# To which values of $a$ is the following an inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Given the following inner space over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$:
>   $$
> \left< \left(\begin{pmatrix}
> x_{1}\\
> x_{2}
> \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
> y_{1}\\
> y_{2}
> \end{pmatrix}\right)  \right> =x_{1} y_{1} -3x_{1} y_{2} \ -3x_{2} y_{1} +ax_{2} y_{2} \  
> $$
>   To which values of $a$ is it an inner space?

I figured it has to do with the positive/definite property since I already checked for the other twos and it's true for any values of $a$.

But I don't understand how am I supposed to solve such equation:

$x_{1} y_{1} -3x_{1} y_{2} \ -3x_{2} y_{1} +ax_{2} y_{2} \ \geqslant 0$

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: **HINT** The inequality must hold for all choices of $x_i, y_i$. For example, if $x_1=0=y_1$, we have $ax_2y_2 \ge 0$.

Comment: I'm starting to think there is no such value that would always make it true, but it's only an assumption.

Comment: That's because, as in the example you mentioned, if $x_{1} \ =\ y_{1} \ =\ 0$, then it must be true that $ax_{2} y_{2} \geqslant 0$, but there is no value of $a$ that would always guarantee such thing, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check positive definiteness, you should check the inner product of $x$ with *itself*, not with a general $y$. Hence, your inequality becomes

$$
\langle x_1,x_2\rangle_a:=x_1^2-6x_1x_2+a x_2^2\geq 0
$$
Now, this is a quadratic in $x_2$ with discriminant $36x_1^2-4ax_1^2=(36-4a)x_1^2$. Now, in order for the quadratic to always be strictly positive for $x_1\neq 0$, it must have no root, so the discriminant must be negative, which happens if and only if $a > \frac{36}{4}$ for $x_1\neq 0$.

Now, we must check that for such a choice of $a$, the constant sign of the inner product is positive, no matter the value of $x_1,x_2$. To this end, we see for $a>\frac{36}{4}$ that the above quadratic is convex and hence, for such an $a$ and $x_1\neq 0$, 
$$
\lim_{x_2\to\infty} \langle x_1,x_2\rangle_a=\infty,
$$
implying that $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle_a\geq 0$ for all $x_2$, since the quadratic has no root and hence, constant sign.
If $x_2\neq 0$ and $x_1=0$, then positivity is obvious.

We conclude that for $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_a$ is positive definite if and only if $a>\frac{36}{4}$..

Comment: Right, I forgot that detail, thank you so much!

Comment: If I have a question if $ a\ =\ \frac{36}{4} $, then we get: $=\ ( x_{1} -3x_{2})^{2}$, which is a power so it must always be positive for any value of $x_{1} ,\ x_{2}$. So why isn't $ a\ =\ \frac{36}{4} $ good?

Comment: If $x_1=3x_2$, then the expression is $0$, so the inner product of $(3,1)$ with itself is $0$. Thus, the bilinear form defined is not strictly positive and thus, only defines a semi-norm. Otherwise, it works just fine. :)